# Organization repos not appearing in list of repos on Codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, aws-codepipeline

I've transferred a private repo from my account to an organization which I'm an owner of. I had no trouble setting up actions for my Amplify apps, but I'm struggling with my custom pipeline for my API deployed on EC2.

AWS connector appears in the list of installed GitHub apps on my personal profile, but not on the organization profile. Amplify configured this automatically and installed an app on the organization account. I managed to find a workaround which involved removing third-party restrictions, but I imagine this can't be secure.

I can't find a way to get AWS to request access to my organization's repos and so can't install the connection.

Answer (score 0):

My organization suddenly appeared in the list of accounts I could connect to when setting up the connection. Not entirely sure why, but managed to resolve it.